# Lua or C++ in Cococ2d-x

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, lua, cocos2d-x

I am going to use Cocos2d-x to make a game for Android and ios, but my question is, do I use the Lua integration or only c++, I see Lua useful here because the compilation thing.

Or do I use only Lua for the configuration, save data and things in runtime?

I don´t know if using Lua for the whole game is the right thing :/

Can anyone help me with this question and why use it or not?

Thanks

Comment: This is a "which technology" question (as well as being extremely broad) and is consequently off-topic for this site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You would use both. Lua can be used for:

- Exporting code to a mobile device
- Making a UI (You should try first make an addon for a MMORPG if you want to get a better idea how you can use Lua)

C++ is the core code of the videogame, so maybe you can program a game without Lua but it might help you to do better UI for your games